# this site can't be reached with valet

Tags: laravel-valet

[image: valet error]

i want domain can be load
I've followed the proper installation but still can't, I followed the install method on this website.
https://medium.com/@samimrezgui123/how-to-install-laravel-valet-on-windows-os-afdc23d69719

Answer (score 0):

to run the project like hris.test we need to first start valet
with "valet start"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).